# Show and Hide Divs on Click - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show and hide divs ('.element_wrapper') on clicking a cerain '.toggler_btn' so it would show all child divs ('.element_wrapper') that are inside the upper one. Also, it must hide them on the second click. Everything should somehow be done using data-id and data-parent attributes that represent id of a div and a button and ids of parent div.

THE CODE:

```
<div id="wrapper">
            <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="1" data-parent="" style="display:none">
            <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="1" data-parent="" >+/-</button>
            Main Office
            <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
            <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="3" data-parent="1" style="display:none">
            <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="3" data-parent="1" >+/-</button>
            Room 203
            <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
            <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="6" data-parent="3" style="display:none">
            <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="6" data-parent="3" >+/-</button>
            Table 2
            <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
            <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="4" data-parent="1" style="display:none">
            <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="4" data-parent="1" >+/-</button>
            Room 256
            <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
            <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="7" data-parent="4" style="display:none">
            <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="7" data-parent="4" >+/-</button>
            Table 3
            <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
            <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="2" data-parent="" style="display:none">
            <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="2" data-parent="" >+/-</button>
            Not So Main Office
            <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
            <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="5" data-parent="2" style="display:none">
            <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="5" data-parent="2" >+/-</button>
            Room 301
            <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
            <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="8" data-parent="5" style="display:none">
            <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="8" data-parent="5" >+/-</button>
            Table 13
            <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
            <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div[data-parent=""]').show();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.toggler_btn').on('click', function (event) {
            var btn = $('.toggler_btn');
            var elem = $('.element_wrapper');
            if (btn.data('id') == elem.data('id')) {
                elem.show();
            }
        })
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What problem are you having with the code shown? The `data-parent` attributes don't seem necessary: can't you just use some combination of `.closest()` or `.parents()` and `.find()` to get the clicked button's wrappers and associated nested items?

Comment: @nnnnnn I think they're necessary, since its data from the database. Or maybe try it your way, how would I do that exactly. I'm new to JS so I've tried a lot already, still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quite understand your question. Maybe you can try this and see if it is what you are looking for.

```
$('.toggler_btn').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    // Show or hide all child elements of the button clicked
    $('.element_wrapper[data-parent="' + id + '"]').toggle();
});
```

p.s. I have not tested this out yet

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `this` and `siblings` to make items relative.  Currently you're just fetching the first element and trying to toggle based on that. Additionally, I wrapped the content inside a class called content.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div[data-parent=""]').show();
    
    $('.toggler_btn').on('click', function (event) {
        $(this).siblings().toggle()
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="1" data-parent="" style="display:none">
  <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="1" data-parent="" >+/-</button>
  <div class="content">
    Main Office
    <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
    <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
  </div>
<div class="element_wrapper" data-id="3" data-parent="1" style="display:none">
  <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="3" data-parent="1" >+/-</button>
  <div class="content">
    Room 203
    <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
    <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
  </div>
<div class="element_wrapper" data-id="6" data-parent="3" style="display:none">
  <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="6" data-parent="3" >+/-</button>
  <div class="content">
    Table 2
    <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
    <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="element_wrapper" data-id="4" data-parent="1" style="display:none">
  <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="4" data-parent="1" >+/-</button>
  <div class="content">
    Room 256
    <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
    <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
  </div>
<div class="element_wrapper" data-id="7" data-parent="4" style="display:none">
  <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="7" data-parent="4" >+/-</button>
  <div class="content">
    Table 3
    <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
    <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="element_wrapper" data-id="2" data-parent="" style="display:none">
  <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="2" data-parent="" >+/-</button>
  Not So Main Office
  <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
  <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
  <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
<div class="element_wrapper" data-id="5" data-parent="2" style="display:none">
  <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="5" data-parent="2" >+/-</button>
  Room 301
  <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
  <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
  <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
<div class="element_wrapper" data-id="8" data-parent="5" style="display:none">
  <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="8" data-parent="5" >+/-</button>
  Table 13
  <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
  <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
  <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The nesting within the HTML structure makes the parent/child relationship clear without the `data-parent` attributes (at least, it does for the example shown), so you can just use a combination of `.closest()` and `.find()` (to get all descendants) or `.children()` (for immediate children only) to get the nested `.element_wrapper` elements that are within the clicked button's wrapper:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[data-parent=""]').show();

  $('.toggler_btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".element_wrapper").children(".element_wrapper").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
div { margin: 5px 15px; border: thin black solid; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="1" data-parent="" style="display:none">
    <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="1" data-parent="">+/-</button> Main Office
    <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
    <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="3" data-parent="1" style="display:none">
      <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="3" data-parent="1">+/-</button> Room 203
      <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
      <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
      <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
      <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="6" data-parent="3" style="display:none">
        <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="6" data-parent="3">+/-</button> Table 2
        <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
        <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="4" data-parent="1" style="display:none">
      <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="4" data-parent="1">+/-</button> Room 256
      <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
      <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
      <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
      <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="7" data-parent="4" style="display:none">
        <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="7" data-parent="4">+/-</button> Table 3
        <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
        <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="2" data-parent="" style="display:none">
    <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="2" data-parent="">+/-</button> Not So Main Office
    <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
    <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="5" data-parent="2" style="display:none">
      <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="5" data-parent="2">+/-</button> Room 301
      <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
      <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
      <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
      <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="8" data-parent="5" style="display:none">
        <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="8" data-parent="5">+/-</button> Table 13
        <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
        <button class="edit_btn" type="button">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete_btn" type="button">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. That works. Though it does show all divs inside other divs.

Comment: Your question said "so it would show all child divs". I thought you meant all descendants, not just direct children. You can change `.find()` to `.children()` to only do the next level, and I've done so with an edit to my question. (In that case you don't need the test I had for whether children were currently visible, just `.toggle()` with no params works.) Anyway, either way, my main point was to show how to do it without needing the `data-` attributes.